# How to open downloaded file using .openFileDescriptor()

Tags: android

I used to open a downloaded file using the following code :

> ```
> final String filePath = cursor.getString(
>                         cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
>                     if (TextUtils2.isNotEmpty(filePath)) {
>                         apkFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
>                     }
>                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
>                                     .setDataAndType(apkFile, UPDATE_APK_FILE_MIME_TYPE)
>                                     .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
> ```

But from API 24 DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME is deprecated and I need to use openFileDescriptor (Uri uri, 
                String mode) method instead.
But I don't know how i can get the file path from the Fd to use it as data for the intent.

Does anyone know how to do it or whats the alternative to open downloaded file ?

Comment: "But I don't know how i can get the file path from the Fd to use it as data for the intent." -- you can't. "whats the alternative to open downloaded file ? " -- you were the one who told `DownloadManager` where to put the content, via your `DownloadManager.Request` and the `setDestination...` series of methods. Hence, you already know where the content is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME)
```

you can use

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)
```

which return the uri for apk file you need

Comment: its working for the downloading part, but in my case, to open the file, i need to use FileProvider, because i'm downloading new apk as part of self update mechanism, and to open the file, the os uses its own app, and because it uses other app to open it, it needs to use FileProvider.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the good old absolute path of the downloaded file just :

```
String absolutePath =  Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))).getPath();
```

And of course :

```
File file = new File(absolutePath);
```